# Obter elementos de uma lista que não estão em outra

Tags: python, lista

Tenho duas listas cujo o conteúdo de uma se refere a um *arquivo1.txt* e a outra um *arquivo2.txt*, existem diferenças no conteúdo dos arquivos e desejo buscar **somente o dado que está em arquivo2.txt e não está em arquivo1.txt**, não me interessa o inverso.

É possível resolver isso com um laço o qual compara se o elemento 0 pertencente ao *arquivo2.txt* está presente em alguma posição da lista do arquivo1.txt, o problema é que teria que percorrer toda essa lista. 

Há uma maneira **mais fácil e simplificada** de fazer esse match de listas em Python?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Imagino que isso resolva o seu problema:

```
lista_final = list(set(lista_arquivo_2) - set(lista_arquivo_1))
```

Considerando que `lista_arquivo_1` e `lista_arquivo_2` são listas válidas em Python.

Como o @BrunoRB citou, isso não retornará elementos repetidos da lista, caso você queira que tenha elementos repetidos, você pode usar a seguinte compressão de lista:

```
lista_final = [x for x in lista_arquivo_2 if x not in lista_arquivo_1]
```

Comment: Note apenas que duplicatas serão removidas, por exemplo caso você possua dois elementos `"hi"` em `lista_arquivo_2` (e exista um `"hi"` em `lista_arquivo_1`) o resultado final vai conter apenas um `"hi"` ao invés de dois e a ordem também não será preservada.

Comment: Note que a situação que "mantém os elementos repetidos" inclui implicitamente o laço que percorre toda a lista_arquivo_1 para cada item em lista_arquivo_2 - o algoritmo fica O(N²). A grande vantagem do exemplo com sets é que busca em conjuntos (`set`) em Python são feitas em tempo constante.

Answer (score -1):

Talvez se você usar a expressão:

```
list(filter(lambda x: x in lista1, lista2))
```